# React bootstrap default selected value for dropdown

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I was using react-bootstrap library and I wanted to have default `selected` value.

I went through their docs and I wasn't able to find anything related to pass/set default value.

This is how I am currently using

```
const dropDownQuestion = (props) => {
  const { options, upsideEmit, value } = props
  return (
    <DropdownButton
      id="dropdown-basic-button"
      onSelect={(eventKey) => upsideEmit(eventKey)}
    >
      {options.map((element) => (
        <Dropdown.Item key={element.id}>{element.value}</Dropdown.Item>
      ))}
    </DropdownButton>
  )
}
```

Where **value** happens to be optional **default Value**. Can someone help me how to achieve this with react-bootstrap dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you mean by *default value*. If you mean value that **appears on the dropdown button** before the user touch it, you can simply insert it (hard-coded or by variable) as the text of the `Dropdown.Toggle`, for example:

```
<Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown-basic">
    Your "default value" here 
</Dropdown.Toggle>
```

If by *default value* you mean the **value of the dropdown's selected item** before the user touch it, it's up to you, by choosing it in the data structure you use to set the values, for example:

```
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
let chosenValue=options[0] // The "default Value"
function onSelect(eventKey, event) { // user can change the "default value"
chosenValue=eventKey;
.
.
.
}


<Dropdown onSelect={onSelect}>
    <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown-basic" />
    <Dropdown.Menu>
      {options.map(option => (
        <Dropdown.Item
          eventKey={option}
          key={option}>
          {option}
        </Dropdown.Item>
      ))}
   </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `active` prop on the `Dropdown.Item` to highlight it, if that's what you mean?

A `DropdownButton` isn't designed as an input, so you can't have a "default value", each item in the menu is rendered as a button.